# replace value if string ends with certain value pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

As titled.

I have written my code but it does not work. I wish I can get a more pythonic way of writing the code (in one single line perhaps).

`clean_df` :

```
columnA
 123F
 FVGD
 w999Z
 678Q
 6y6yA
```

My code :

```
postfix = ["A", "D", "Z", "P"]

for value in postfix:
    if cleaned_data['columnA'].str.endswith(value) is True:
        cleaned_data['columnA'] = value
    else:
        cleaned_data['columnA'] = "blah"
```

The `postfix` are constant. Expected outcome :

```
columnA
 blah
  D
  Z
 blah
  A
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one line with a list comprehension:

```
postfix = ["A", "D", "Z", "P"]
cleaned_data['columnA'] = [value[-1] if value[-1] in postfix else "blah" for value in cleaned_data['columnA']]
```

The output is :

```
columnA
 blah
  D
  Z
 blah
  A
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this with [`pd.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) here.

```
pat = "|".join(postfix)
pat = f"({pat}$"
df['columnA'] = df['columnA'].str.extract(pat, expand=False).fillna('blah')
df
  columnA
0    blah
1       D
2       Z
3    blah
4       A
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple one-liner would be

```
df['columnA'] = np.where(df.columnA.str[-1].isin(postfix), df.columnA.str[-1], 'blah')
```

`np.where` takes in a condition, value if the condition is True and value if the condition is False.

**OR**

In pure pandas, without using numpy, it would be

```
df['columnA'] = df.columnA.str[-1].where(df.columnA.str[-1].isin(postfix), 'blah')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

**Note:** `str.endswith` accepts a `tuple` also.

```
In [3933]: import numpy as np

In [3934]: df.columnA = np.where(df.columnA.str.endswith(tuple(postfix)), df.columnA.str[-1], 'blah')

In [3935]: df
Out[3935]: 
  columnA
0    blah
1       D
2       Z
3    blah
4       A
```